# Spring Boot can't start on JDK 17 : module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

I am migrating a Spring Boot app from JDK 8 to JDK 17.

But in JDK 17 I have the following error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1356d4d4
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:577) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ContextTypeMatchClassLoader$ContextOverridingClassLoader.isEligibleForOverriding(ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.java:99) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.core.OverridingClassLoader.loadClass(OverridingClassLoader.java:87) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.OverridingClassLoader.loadClass(OverridingClassLoader.java:82) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.loadClass(ContextTypeMatchClassLoader.java:70) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1534) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:704) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:867) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:855) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:842) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.pacinformatique.vinotech.mobile.VinotechMobileApplication.main(VinotechMobileApplication.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
```

Adding `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to the VM options works but it looks pretty hacky. I thought that with Spring Boot 2.7 I would've been able to run the app without the VM options.

Have I missed something ?

Comment: I've never needd to set this. Can you go to https://start.spring.io and generate a new project and compare it with yours?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I managed to find the cause : my project uses Load Time Weaving with AspectJ and it looks like AspectJ needs this option to work with JDK 17. If I disable load time weaving I don't get the error. But since I do need load time weaving I'll have to wait for aspectJ to find a solution and use the VM option in the meantime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered that my issue was not so much related to Spring Boot but more to AspectJ load time weaving.

Indeed my project uses Load Time Weaving with AspectJ, and as we can see in the [latest changelog from AspectJ](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-198.html) :

> Use LTW on Java 16+
> Please note that if you want to use load-time weaving on Java 16+, the weaving agent collides with JEP 396 (Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals by Default) and related subsequent JEPs. Therefore, you need to set the JVM parameter --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED in order to enable aspect weaving. This is due to the fact that the weaver uses internal APIs for which we have not found an adequate replacement yet when defining classes in different classloaders

Therefore the VM option is need for my project for now.

Comment: Did aspectJ fixed the issue? or you found a workaround instead of using --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED?

Answer (score 1):

Using maven?

For me this fixed my problem:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>17</source>
    <target>17</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Odd that this should work... but it got me past a boatload of errors.